# How to cover this code?

Tags: apex, unit-test

How to cover this code?
[image]

[image]
 Test class Code

```
     @isTest static void getPageNumberListTest(){
    Controller controller = new Controller();  
    controller.TotalPages=10;
    controller.getPageNumberList();

}
```

Conroller Class

```
public Integer TotalPages {
get {   
    if (setList.getResultSize() <= 10)
        this.TotalPages = 1;
    if (Math.Mod ( setList.getResultSize(), setList.getPageSize() ) == 0)
        this.TotalPages = ( setList.getResultSize() / setList.getPageSize() );
    if (Math.Mod ( setList.getResultSize(), setList.getPageSize() ) != 0)
     this.TotalPages = ( setList.getResultSize() / setList.getPageSize() )+1;
    return TotalPages;
}
set;
```

}

```
public Integer TotalRecords {
    get { 
        this.TotalRecords = setList.getResultSize();
        return TotalRecords;
    }
    set;
}
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setList {
get {
    if (setList == null) { 
        setList = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
        [SELECT  Name, Email, Contact_Level__c, AccountID, OwnerID, CreatedByID, CreatedDate FROM Contact]));
    }
    if (this.PageSize == null) PageSize = 10; 
    setList.setPageSize(PageSize); 


    return setList;
} set;
```

}
[image]

Comment: Does `TotalPages` or `TotalRecords` have a getter or setter? If so, please [edit] to include them.

Comment: your testmethod needs to create Contacts;

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a 11 records and pass them into standard controller constructor.

Then pass standard controller into custom controller constructor and assert that TotalPages is 2 and TotalRecords is 11.

Also create another test method for which create 10 records and pass them into standard controller constructor.

Then pass standard controller into custom controller constructor and assert that TotalPages is 1 and TotalRecords is 10.

These two test methods would give the full coverage

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mentioned way:

```
ApexPages.StandardController standardcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(sObjectRecord);
ConrollerClass classInstance = new ConrollerClass(standardcontroller);
classInstance.TotalPages();
classinstance.getPageNumberList();
```

Comment: Variable does not exist: sObjectRecord

Comment: You need to include the sObject you are working with. Here I could see that iT is Contact. So, get a Contact record and pass the reference in place of sObject.

Comment: Contact con = new Contact(FirstName='sadsa',LastName ='dasdsa',Email='dsadas@mail.ru',Contact_Level__c='Primary');
        ApexPages.StandardController standardcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(con);
        Controller controller = new Controller(standardcontroller);